# MATLAB: Counting the number of overlaps of an element in multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, overlap, counting

I have 2 arrays where

```
A = [1,0,0,1,1,0,1]

B = [1,0,1,1,0,0,1]
```

I want to find the number of occurrences 1 appears in both arrays (in this case, 3). How do I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements? Is the test if `A` and `B` at a particular index are both `1`?

Comment: @Jon Surrell, yes, that's exactly it. Turns out matrix multiplication works perfectly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write it like this:

```
C=sum(A.*B);
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the row vectors consist only of `0` and `1`, you could use **matrix multiplication**, which may be the fastest approach:

```
result = A*B.';
```

Comment: What if you do `(1-(~A))*(1-(~B).');` for matrices that contain other numbers than zero? It seems quick on my machine....

Comment: @kkuilla Or `double(logical(A))*double(logical(B).')`, which may be a little faster

Answer (score 3):

Instead of summing up you could also count the **number** of **non-zero**-elements with [**`nnz`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nnz.html).

```
nnz(A.*B)
```

It won't beat [**Adiel's**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30457892/2605073) and [**Luis Mendo's**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30460926/2605073) **solution**, how this small unsophisticated benchmark shows:

```
A = randi(2,1,100000)-1;
B = randi(2,1,100000)-1;

f1 = @() nnz(A.*B);
f2 = @() sum(A.*B);
f3 = @() sum(A&B);
f4 = @() sum(all([A;B]));
f5 = @() A*B.'; %'

t(1) = timeit(f1);
t(2) = timeit(f2);
t(3) = timeit(f3);
t(4) = timeit(f4);
t(5) = timeit(f5);
```

---

```
t =  0.0005  %// thewaywewalk
     0.0002  %// Adiel
     0.0010  %// kkuilla
     0.0026  %// Santhan Salai
     0.0001  %// Luis Mendo
```

It would have the advantage, that it works also for arrays with values other than just zeros and ones.

Comment: Could you add my approach please? And I think you should use row (not column) vectors as inputs, as per the OP

Comment: @LuisMendo I included all changes, and yes, your solution seems to be the fastest!

Comment: Thanks! In Matlab, matrix multiplication is always the fastest :-)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `&` as well. This would work on non-zero values as well.

```
sum(A&B)

ans =  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use of `all` could be one alternative:

```
C = sum(all([A;B]))
```